# how to call two functions from inside a third one

Tags: php

I have created a page called User.php, I created inside it three public functions:

```
public function createUser() {
    // to insert the data of the user into a database
}

public function AddRole() {
    // to insert the role of the new created user into the same database but of course another table
}

public function register(){ //to call the first two function    
    $conn = getConn();
    createUser();
    AddRole();
}
```

then I called the function register() from another page called registerCtrl.php

```
 $id = $thisUser->register() ;
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function createUser() in C:\wamp\www\imp\models\User.php on line 114

I think that the problem is in the way I am calling the two functions inside the third one, of course this is only my opinion.
NB: I am new in coding and this is my first software.
thank you guys.

Comment: Is this inside a class? If so, it should be `$this->createUser()` and `$this->AddRole()`

Answer (score 4):

When calling a member function of a class, you need to link it to an instance of that class, in the above case you want to call it on the instance your currently working with, which is `this`.  So the call should be...

```
$this->createUser() ;
$this->AddRole() ;
```

Also **if** `$conn` is meant to be an instance variable, you also need to prefix it with `$this->`...

```
$this->conn = $this->getConn();
```

(Also depends on where `getConn()` is defined)

Comment: `$this->$conn` - the second `$` is probably typo (unlikely it's variable property name).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you don't have a class. In PHP you can create functions without a class Then you try to acces to the function with an Object.

Try to include the file  User.php. `require('User.php')` or `include('User.php')` in the registerCtrl.php-File at top. Then just use `register();`

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function createUser() in C:\wamp\www\imp\models\User.php on line 114 -> this means that the Interpreter cant find the function.